# Performance: Looping through array to update positions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I'm developing a relatively simple Cordova application and I'm trying to position elements around the screen based on device orientation.

I'm listening for a change in orientation and firing an event:

```
window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', function(e) {
  doTheThings(e.alpha);
});

$scope.doTheThings(d) {
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.myThings.length; i++) {
    // I've calculated their bearing to the user already. myThings is an array of objects.

    var compass = $scope.myThings[i].bearing - degree;
    if (compass < 0) {
        compass = 360 + compass;
    } else if (compass > 360) {
        compass = ((compass / 360) - 1) * 360;
    }

    var top = 0;
                var left = 0;

                // TOP if 315 - 44 (LEFT SET)
                if (compass > 314 || compass <= 44) {
                    if (compass > 314) {
                        left = ((compass - 315) / 45) * halfCanvas;
                    } else {
                        left = ((compass / 45) * halfCanvas) + (halfCanvas);
                    }
                } else if (compass > 44 && compass <= 134) {
                    left = canvasMaxWidth;
                    top = ((compass - 45) / 90) * canvasMaxHeight;
                } else if (compass > 134 && compass <= 224) {
                    top = canvasMaxHeight;
                    left = (1 - ((compass - 135) / 90)) * canvasMaxWidth;
                } else if (compass > 224 && compass <= 314) {
                    top = (1 - ((compass - 225) / 90)) * canvasMaxHeight;
                }
                $scope.$apply(function() {
                    $scope.myThings[i].positioned = true;
                    $scope.myThings[i].top = top;
                    $scope.myThings[i].left = left;
                });

  } 
}
```

It's not terribly complex code and it gets the job done. I'm displaying the items in the DOM as follows:

```
<div ng-repeat="thing in myThings" style="transform: translate3d({{ thing.left }}px, {{ thing.top }}px, 0px);">
  Yay!
</div>
```

Works a treat on a powerful device (My Nexus 6P and Nexus 5), but slows a little with 15ish objects, but is essentially a slideshow on slower devices (iPhone 4s, for example). It renders maybe once every couple seconds - totally brutal and unacceptable.

I figure I'm probably doing something wrong here and there's a way to optimize this somehow. Any help?

Comment: `$scope.apply()` is not needed when updating the bindings from Angular code.

Comment: Have you tried to execute your doTheThings method periodically like every half second, instead of calling it everytime the deviceorientation event is called? I guess this event is called a lot, if your performance suffers...

Comment: Anyway the `if (compass > 314 || compass <= 44) {
                    if (compass > 314) {
                        left = ((compass - 315) / 45) * halfCanvas;
                    } else {
                        left = ((compass / 45) * halfCanvas) + (halfCanvas);
                    }` part seems to have a redundant if clause.